# How to clean up drivers loading at startup

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit

I have 2 Acronis drivers loading at startup that should not be.

I uninstalled Acronis from my system and rebooted, but 2 Acronis drivers are still loading, any advice on how to get these cleaned up and out of Windows startup?

I tried reinstalling and using Revo uninstaller, but that did not help.

I have searched the registry for the drivers but have never used this method to remove startup drivers before and don't want to make things worse.

Update:

I used Autoruns to prevent the drivers from loading, rebooted then used regedit to remove them from the proper registry locations.

Comment: +1 I am using votes up, so I thought I would read your questions. :) Thus all the +5's.

Comment: @ KCotreau, you used the MS Thin PC OS yet? 90 day free trial...http://www.microsoft.com/windows/enterprise/solutions/virtualization/products/thinpc.aspx

Comment: No, and frankly, I had not even heard of it. Thanks. I only have one client with a major Terminal Services environment, but they also do so much more outside of that, I am not sure it would be appropriate for anyone I work with right now.

Comment: Its been too long but more than likely it was Acronis 9 or 10 (image software) Yes I will delete the Acronis tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try disabling/removing them with [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902).

Comment: Dang, I forgot about that proggy, thanks, worked like a charm, it also showed me where to look in the registry.

Comment: @Moab heck, I never know about autoruns, so thanks to both of you. :D

Answer (score 0):

You could hunt about for them in Device Manager - type "devmgmnt.msc" in the "Run..." box on the start menu (you don't say which Windows version you're running, so it's hard to be more specific than that).  Select "Show Hidden Devices" from the "view menu".  These drivers are likely to be in the "Non P&P devices" section.  Look for something that says "True Image", right click on the device and select properties, then match the service names above on the Driver tab.  Once you have found the right device, close the property box, right click on its name in the device manager list, and select "Uninstall". Repeat for the second driver.

Failing this, you could manually delete the files as follows (although I take no responsibility if this renders your machine unbootable).

Hold down the F8 key while starting Windows, and you should get a startup menu. Select "Safe mode with command prompt only".  You should then be able to delete the files by typing

```
del C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\tifsfilt.sys
del C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\timntr.sys
```

Comment: Manually deleting them or renaming them to .bak causes a x07 bsod on startup. eek! I recovered though.

Comment: Glad you were sensible and took backups.  I can't think of anything else other than going through device manager with a fine tooth comb, or possibly re-installing then uninstalling True Image.

Comment: Autoruns as suggested by Mehrdad fixed it,